# How do I calculate the sum of 2 columns using the max from each row based on a condition?

Tags: google-sheets

I have data in two columns. I would like to sum the two columns (A and B) based on the max value in each row and a condition (c) indicating if the row should be included in the sum. Example:

```
A    B    C
1    4    No
2    3    Yes
3    2    Yes
2    1    Yes
1    0    Yes
```

The result would be 3+3+2+1=9. Data is the first row should not be included because the condition in column C states "No".

I have been able to sum the values using the arrayformula below but have not been able to figure out how to add the condition.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(A1:A>B1:B,A1:A,B1:B)))`

I am using Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular example, you can use a `SUMPRODUCT` formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5*(A1:A5>=B1:B5)*(C1:C5="Yes"))+(B1:B5*(B1:B5>A1:A5)*(C1:C5="Yes")))
```

This approach may be clumsy in your real world example, though. If your real data is more complicated, post a snippet that shows that complication and I can take a more advanced crack at it.

Comment: This works nicely except it does not handle equal values in the same row. They are ignored. Adding the ">" appears to work great.(A1:A5>=B1:B5)

Comment: @ScottCravens That's a good point and I missed it. I updated the formula so future reader's won't have to catch the comments to get it to work for them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a one-cell solution, but you can just put the following formula in a helper column:

> =IF(C1="No",0,IF(A1>B1,A1,B1))

If you copy that formula all the way down col D, the values can be summed to arrive at the value you are looking for.

[image]